# Shortcut to insert row in Excel

Tags: ms-office

I see a reference showing the shortcut to be `Ctl-Shift-I` : but it is not working on Excel for Mac 2015

https://exceljet.net/keyboard-shortcuts/insert-rows

[image]

Is there any working shortcut for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested command shift + and control shift + on excel 2016 on a mac - both add a row as long as the row is selected.

If the row is not selected then it will shift the cells down in that row.

For Excel 2011, then control i works to add a row if the row is selected, if only a cell is selected then it brings up the insert cell dialogue.
In excel 2011 command i does italic.

For command-shift-i this does italic on the selected row - the version using control does not work (excel 2106).

That website has information that appears out of date.

Comment: `Command-Shift-+` does in fact work. That is not a combination mentioned in the docs. Thanks .

Comment: I sent a message to that site - they still insist that ctrl i adds a row when all it does is toggle italic.... perhaps they should test it in excel and see...

Answer (score 1):

Try command-shift-i instead of control-shift-i.  Ctl key is usually used on a windows machine and many of the comparable commands on Macs use the command key.

Comment: I tried all sorts of combinations - that was one of the first ones. That one just turns to Italics

Answer (score 1):

Because 'Rows' under 'Insert' is a unique menu item in Excel, a MacOS keyboard shortcut can be created for it.

- Keyboard control panel > Shortcuts tab > App Shortcuts
- Click '+' to add a shortcut
- App: Excel
- Menu title: Rows
- Keyboard shortcut: invent one that doesn't conflict with other apps or menus.